# Error advancing a list iterator in std::copy

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using std::list;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::iterator;
int main()
{
    list<int> list_int{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    list<int> list_int2;

    copy(list_int.crbegin()+3 , list_int.crbegin()+8,back_inserter(list_int2));
    for (auto &ele : list_int2)
        cout << ele << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

what is the wrong?I am so confused.I think the wrong is about the copy function.

error：

[image]

Comment: Make your title describe the problem please. You can see that other questions on SO are not just "why is my code wrong"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot advance a list [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) (bidirectional non-random) by incrementing it with more than one. In other words, only `operator++` and `operator--` are defined for bi-directional iterators. Use [`std::next`](https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/tutorial-on-tag-dispatching/) instead,

```
copy(std::next(list_int.crbegin(), 3), 
     std::next(list_int.crbegin(), 8),
     back_inserter(list_int2));
```

`std::next` will [tag-dispatch](https://crazycpp.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/tutorial-on-tag-dispatching/) to the correct internal iterator function which in effect will increment the iterator one by one repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

`list_int` and `list_int2` are of type `std::list`. Iterators of `std::list` do not support random access. Therefore you cannot advance them by adding an integer like `list_int.crbegin() + 3`.

You can make a copy of the list iterators and use `std::advance` to advance them. See [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance%60)

Comment: *"Iterators of std::list are not bi-directional."* They *are* bi-directional, they are not random iterators.